# Displaying unicode in a django template

Tags: django, templates, unicode

I feel there's an obvious answer to this...

I've got a list of unicode values that I want to use in a django template.

The models...

```
# models.py
class MyModel( models.Model ):
    # ...
    def my_char_fields(self):
        return AnotherModel.objects.filter(mymodel=self.pk).values_list('cf').distinct()

class AnotherModel( models.Model ):
    # ...
    cf = models.CharField( max_length=6 )
    mymodel = ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

And in my template...

```
#MyTemplate.html
<ul>
{% for cf in mymodel.my_char_fields %}
<li>cf</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The result is stuff like:

- (u'BL',)
- (u'M24',)

but it should be:

- BL
- M24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass `flat=True` to [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list).

Comment: "it returns tuples when iterated over"

Comment: Ahhh so the "correct" BL,M24 are in fact unicode strings? They just get displayed differently when they're printed in tuple?

Comment: When printed in a larger structure, the `repr()` of the element is printed instead of the `str()` or `unicode()`.